# Debugging compatibility issues in MS Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I created a tool in Excel that relies on VBA (internal functions only as far as I'm aware). I sent it out to users for testing. One user runs Excel on a Mac and cannot even open the file without a warning about compatibility and resulting restrictions to read only.

Since I don't have a Mac around yet to test, I was wondering if there is a way of pinning down what the problematic parts are in such a case. In Office 2019 Pro for Windows, compatibility checks offered by Excel do not include any Mac versions.

**Update:** I know now that the VBA parts actually work but still get the message that the file is not compatible with Mac when opening it. Is there a way to track down what exactly causes that message so as to get rid of it?

Comment: You could use screensharing to debug on the users machine if you don't have access to a Mac. Teamviewer is cross compatible. For VBA on the Mac Ron de Bruin is pretty much the authority: https://www.rondebruin.nl/